# Querying Binary data using Django and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to print out to the console the actual content value (which is html) of the field 'htmlfile': 16543. (See below)

So far I am able to print out the whole row using .values() method

Here is what I am getting in my python shell:

```
>>>
>>> Htmlfiles.objects.values()[0]
{'id': 1, 'name': 'error.html', 'htmlfile': 16543}
>>>
```

I want to print out the content of 16543.. I have scanned through the Django QuerySet docs so many times and still cannot find the right method..

Here is my data model in models.py:

```
class Htmlfiles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    htmlfile = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'htmlfiles'
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want to print out the content of 16543". Do you mean you want to print only the value of the `htmlfile` field? Also it would be clearer if you posted your model class.

Comment: Yes, the value inside the htmlfile field.. I have added the model above

Comment: You should probably use a JsonField rather than TextField, then you can use the Postgres-specific query extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch only the `htmlfield` value with:

```
Htmlfiles.objects.values('htmlfile')
```

Which, for each row, will give you an dictionary like so:

```
{'htmlfile': 12345}
```

So to print all the htmlfile values something like this is what you need:

```
objects = Htmlfiles.objects.values('htmlfile')
for obj in objects:
    print(obj['htmlfile'])
```

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot more sense, however I just want one value not all of them. Something like this print(obj['htmlfile'])[0] ??

Comment: If you want only one value then you first need to filter the query to fetch only one object - e.g., `Htmlfiles.objects.get(... some filter here...).values('htmlfile')`. But you need to know which object you want first.

Comment: I tried this .. Htmlfiles.objects.get(htmlfile=16543).values('htmlfile') and got back this error: AttributeError: 'Htmlfiles' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that... what is the point of fetch the value of a field if you just fetched the object based on that field value itself?

Comment: But if you do want to do it, then simply do : `Htmlfiles.objects.get(htmlfile=16543).htmlfile`

Comment: Because I want the specific contents stored inside htmlfile:16543 so I can send it to the browser ... But first I just want it to print out the html in the console so that I know it works ..

Comment: I know this is unusual and unconventional but I'm not doing this by my own choice ..